# Ruby gets method makes command prompt crash

Tags: ruby, powershell, unicode, command-prompt, codepages

I am currently making an app that deals with Ancient Greek (Unicode extended) characters. To put it simple, the user types a word in Greek and the program analyses it morphologically and shows all its declension, i. e. all its possible forms. Pretty simple, I am new to this. I made it with Latin (a language with no special Unicode characters) a week ago and it works perfectly.

I work with Ruby 3.0.2 and the Command Prompt attached to its installation file. I can write code using Greek Unicode letters (like "puts "ἀγαθός"") and they are displayed on the Command Prompt without problem. UTF-8 works fine there. I think the default codepage is UTF-8 for the .rb file.

The problem is when the Command Prompt tries to recognize the letters the user has written. To test recognition, when the user writes a word, the program shows again the letters written (I wrote them using the Windows Polytonic Greek Keyboard). To my disgrace these letters are only squares with question marks inside them. After a while, I couldn't write any single Greek character (not even non-Unicode-extended) because the command prompt crashes after doing it.

One solution I made was to change, before running the program, the codepage to Windows-1253, which supports Greek characters but not Unicode characters. That made possible to write Greek common characters and the command prompt recognizes them well. But of course it continues crashing if I dare to write a single alpha with spiritus asper.

But I really would like to use UTF-8 for everything, and I don't know why the program is doing this. Of course Windows Powershell does the same.

I hope I have explained the problem well. Sorry if my language is not appropriate, but I hope you have got the point. Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this as a command line script (e.g. `ruby /your/path/to/file.rb`)? If so some other posts have suggested adding the `-K` option might help like so `ruby -KU /your/path/to/file.rb` [Command Line Options](https://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/rubyworld.html) others have suggested the `-Eutf-8` option although I cannot find this documented anywhere.

Comment: I tried to do as you said (I have read that suggestion before) but it doesn't work. I think the problem is not of Ruby but of the console, because whenever I change the codepage the translation to bytes is different and works better with Windows-1253 than with UTF-8 for common Greek characters.

Comment: Maybe the characters I type from my keyboard are read as if they were from a modification of Windows-1253 (the so-called "Polytonic Greek") and the console reads them as if they were UTF-8, so it reads them as invalid byte sequences.